# Help me with sum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

good morning

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 u_0  = 1 \\ 
 u_n  = 3 - \frac{4}{{1 - v_n }} \\ 
 \end{array} \right.\quad  \\ 
 \;v_n  = \left( { - 3} \right)^{n + 1}  \\ 
 s = v_{1436}  + v_{1437}  +  \cdots  + v_{2014}  + v_{2015}  \\ 
 s = \left( { - 3} \right)^{1437} \frac{{1 - \left( { - 3} \right)^{580} }}{4} \\ 
   \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
help me with the sum
$$t = u_{1436}  + u_{1437}  +  \cdots  + u_{2014}  + u_{2015}$$

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  Are you using the software product *Mathematica*?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Hint: read the [documentation for the `Sum` function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html).

Answer (score 1):

My earlier answer resulting from misreading the question.  Taken at face value, you are asking for

```
sum=Sum[3 - 4/(1 - (-3)^(n + 1)), {n, 1436, 2015}]
```

which produces a rationale number with an enormous number of digits.  It is, however, almost precisely equal to `3*(2015 - 1436 + 1)`, or `1740`, as one would expect.

```
N[sum,1000]
(* 1739.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
   9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
   9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
   9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
   9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
   9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
   9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
   9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
   9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999\
   9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999992857039926\
   8513131285413986931474461154920816542991504582031706836805014578400601\
   6924517971816231543396534453863509796478355553439360807774820500515534\
   5427673288846547289780176600828025742232188533914269791267897469548638\
   7278671633510103822747633226807954160428608436494115564482612200851775\
   861924557788159926854 *)
```

Comment: @2012rcampion  You are correct.  I replace the earlier answer. Thanks.